# select dates between two dates with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a start_date and end_date. I want to get the list of dates in between these two dates. Can anyone help me pointing the mistake in my query.

```
id      state   start_date      end_date
------------------------------------------------------------------------
2   New     2016-02-24      2016-02-28 
2   Active  2016-02-28      2016-03-01 
2   New     2016-03-01      NULL
3   New     2016-02-23      2016-02-25 
3   Active  2016-02-25      2016-02-27 
3   New     2016-02-27      NULL

id      state   start_date      end_date
------------------------------------------------------------------------
2   New     2016-02-24      2016-02-25 
2   New     2016-02-25      2016-02-26
2   New     2016-02-26      2016-02-27
2   New     2016-02-27      2016-02-28
2   Active  2016-02-28      2016-02-29
2   Active  2016-02-29      2016-03-01
2   New     2016-03-01      NULL
3   New     2016-02-23      2016-02-24 
3   New     2016-02-24      2016-02-25
3   Active  2016-02-25      2016-02-26
3   Active  2016-02-26      2016-02-27 
3   New     2016-02-27      NULL
```

Comment: Pointing the mistake in your query, that you're not showing us? Contrary to popular belief, we're not mind readers (or at least, not all of the time)

Comment: A simple `BETWEEN` works just fine with *dates*. It won't work if you use stringds instead of dates. You didn't post any query.

Comment: If you want to return every date between the `start_date` and `end_date` join with a calendar table using `ON Calendar.Date between start_date and end_date` as the condition.

Comment: To add to the above comment: [Bones of SQL - The Calendar Table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/calendar/145206/)

Comment: Also [Temporal Data Techniques in SQL Server](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/temporal-data-techniques-in-sql/). Calendar tables and [Numbers](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4176/the-sql-server-numbers-table-explained--part-1/) tables can convert many complex range or date problems into simple joins and range queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don’t have calendar table available , you can try like following query using `master..[spt_values]` to generate the missing dates.

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT ( Row_number() 
                    OVER ( 
                      ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) ) - 1 RN 
         FROM   master..[spt_values] T1) 
SELECT id, 
       state, Dateadd(day, rn, start_date)     AS start_date, 
       Dateadd(day, rn + 1, start_date) AS end_date 
FROM   <Table_Name> t1 
       INNER JOIN cte T2 
               ON Dateadd(day, rn, start_date) < t1.end_date
```

Note: Replace  with appropriate table name.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get all the dates between two dates, the simplest way to do so is using a recursive common table expression (and you avoid depending on undocumented system tables that can change without notice) :

```
declare @start_date date = '2019-1-22';
declare @end_date date = '2019-1-29';    

with GetDates As  
(  
  select @start_date as TheDate
  union all  
  select dateadd(day, 1, TheDate) from GetDates where TheDate < @end_date
)
select TheDate from GetDates;
```

Now you can join your data to the Recursive CTE GetDates.